# Laravel CSP how to allow inline styles in Laravel Mix Webpack

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I am using the [spatie/laravel-csp](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-csp) package to set CSP headers in a Laravel application. But the `inline style` could not be applied and refused with the following error.

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self.'
> 'nonce-TjpZGox5zGathTvJDeVMfxzHaOtWMc7v' 'unsafe-inline'".

Further detail.

1. I am using Laravel 7.
2. /spatie/laravel-csp 2.8
3. "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
4. and inertia with Vue 2

What I have tried so far.

1. specify **webpack_nonce**  @ entry file (main.js) [webpack documentation](https://v4.webpack.js.org/guides/csp/)
2. Using inline scripts and styles as in  spatie/laravel-csp  documentation

Comment: Did you resolve this, without opening up the security with a 'unsafe-inline', which is clearly unadvisable? I'm having the same problem and can't extract the css without some substantial work

Comment: Can you show us the HTML that's causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel try specifying your webpack_nonce in the index.php file.

Answer (score -1):

You can also do your CSP for styles by adding style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';

In your manifest file add this line :

```
"content_security_policy": "default-src 'self' style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
```

This will allow you to keep using the inline style in your extension.

**Note: This is not recommended way to do style tag inline to prevent attacks.**

Comment: I'm not looking for a solution that opens the door to xss attacks. Is there not a solution to import the nonce?

Comment: Can't award the bounty to someone who is answering it with a major security flaw. Sorry.